# Prove that the power set of A minus B is equal to the power set of A minus the power set of B : P(A − B) = P(A) − P(B)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

The question I'm working on says

> "determine for any sets A and B, it is true thatP(A − B) = P(A) −
>   P(B). If it is true prove it, if it is not, give a counterexample"

Slightly unsure about this "for any sets" statement. Do they mean for any specific set? Or for all? If it is true for any specific set then how can a counter example prove falsehood? Maybe I'm answering my own question here.

I'm also going to provide a proof here to see if my logic is making any sense to you folks.

Proof:
P(A − B) = P(A) − P(B)

let X ∈ P(A-B) ⇒ X ∈ A and X ∉ B ⇒ X ∈ P(A) and X ∉ P(B) ⇒ X ∈ P(A) - P(B)

let X ∈ P(A) - P(B) ⇒ X ∈ P(A) and X ∉ P(B) ⇒ X ∈ A and X ∉ B ⇒ X ∈ (A - B) ⇒ X ∈ P(A - B)

so we have P(A − B) = P(A) − P(B)

Comment: "determine for any sets A and B, it is true that..." meats to prove or disprove that the formula is true for every sets $A$ and $B$. In order to disprove it, is enough to fond a specific pair of sets such that the "equation" does not hold.

Comment: The proof is worng... $X \in \mathcal P(A)$ means $X \subseteq A$.

Comment: I think that "determine for any sets A and B, it is true thatP(A − B) = P(A) − P(B)" should be "determine *whether* for any sets A and B, it is true thatP(A − B) = P(A) − P(B)" or even better "determine whether it is true that for any sets A and B, P(A − B) = P(A) − P(B)". I'm not sure if you copied it wrong or your instructor is bad at wording things.

Answer (score 2):

For a counterexample, take $A=\{x,y\}, B=\{y\}$. Then $A-B=\{x\}$, so $$\mathcal P(A-B)=\{\emptyset,\{x\}\}$$
And $$\mathcal P(A)-\mathcal P(B)=\{\emptyset,\{x\},\{y\},\{x,y\}\}-\{\emptyset,\{y\}\}=\text{what?}$$
As you can see, the two expressions are different.

In fact, for a quick general proof that the statement is false, you just have to note that for *any* two sets $A$ and $B$, $\emptyset$ is in $\mathcal P(A-B)$ but not in $\mathcal P(A)-\mathcal P(B)$.

Comment: equal to {{x}, {x,y}}. so not a true statement. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Or a simpler solution, $A=B=\varnothing$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Indeed. As I said, $A$ and $B$ can be any two sets. (Perhaps I should have said any one or two sets?) And I didn't want my example to look too much like a special case.