# Prove that $P(A-B) \subseteq P(A) - P(B)$ is false.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let P denote the power set operator and let A and B be two non-empty sets.

$P(A-B) \subseteq P(A) - P(B)$ is supposed to be false. However, by the following derivation, I can't tell why it is false.

$$\forall x \left[ x \in P(A-B) \rightarrow x \in (P(A) - P(B)) \right]$$

$$\cong \forall x \left[ x \subseteq (A-B) \rightarrow x \in P(A) \setminus  P(B) \right]$$

$$\cong \forall x \left[ \forall y \in x(y \in A \land y \notin B) \rightarrow x \in P(A) \land x \notin P(B)  \right]$$

$$\cong \forall x \left[ \forall y \in x(y \in A \land y \notin B) \rightarrow x \subseteq A \land x \nsubseteq B\right]$$

$$\cong \forall x \left[ \forall y \in x(y \in A \land y \notin B) \rightarrow \forall y \in x (x\in A) \land \forall y\in x(y \notin B)\right]$$

To me, the statement above seem to be correct. Can someone help me point out my mistake(s)?

Note: Before asking this question, I have read this answer:
[Prove that the power set of A minus B is equal to the power set of A minus the power set of B : P(A − B) = P(A) − P(B)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3074586/prove-that-the-power-set-of-a-minus-b-is-equal-to-the-power-set-of-a-minus-the-p). It was not helpful because I was trying to understand why this statement is wrong in terms of logical expressions.

Comment: $\emptyset\in P(A-B)$ but $\emptyset\not\in P(A)-P(B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look to the end of your second last line.  The proper equivalence is an existential, not a universal.

$\ldots~x\nsubseteq B\\\ldots~\neg(x\subseteq B)\\\ldots~\neg(\forall y\in x~.y\in B))\\\ldots~(\exists y\in x~. y\notin B)$

Comment: Thanks! But even if I fix it, the expression would still be true, right?

Comment: ... because the existential is weaker than the universal?

Comment: No, $\forall y\in \emptyset~(y\in A\wedge y\notin B)\to ((\forall y\in\emptyset~y\in A)\wedge(\exists y\in\emptyset~y\notin B))$ is valued false, and the emptyset surely exists, so there is a counterexample.

Comment: Are both the LHS and the RHS false? Can you briefly explain why the LHS is true/false and why the RHS is true/false? I'm a beginner so I'm a bit confused. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\forall y\in\emptyset~P(y)$ is true for *any* predicate since there is nothing in the emptyset that will contradict the claim of universality.  $\exists y\in\emptyset ~P(y)$ is false for any predicate, since there is nothing in the emptyset that may satisfy the claim of existence.  So a statement of the form $(\forall y\in\emptyset~(Q(y)\wedge P(y)))\to((\forall y\in\emptyset~Q(y))\wedge(\exists y\in\emptyset~P(y)))$ is false (as a truth cannot entail a falsehood).

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake comes at the end: $x\nsubseteq B$ is not the same as $\forall y\in x(y\notin B)$. (You wrote $x\notin B$, but I’m pretty sure that that was a typo.) What **is** true is that $x\nsubseteq B$ if and only if $\exists y\in x(y\notin B)$. It takes only **one** member of $x$ not in $B$ to ensure that $x\nsubseteq B$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo, I've corrected it!

Comment: @ZhihanYang: You’re welcome!